# Why did Blackbox tell me “The game isn’t designed to be played like that”

Tags: blackbox

I accidentally triggered a [peculiar message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR2Pp.jpg) while playing Blackbox:

> **Please Stop**: The game isn’t designed to be played like that.

I’m not sure what caused this message to appear, or what behavior the game is referring to.

I think the message may have something to do with the touchscreen, as each puzzle is meant to be solved without touch. However, despite multiple attempts, I haven’t been able to make the message re-appear.

What is the game telling me not to do? What makes this message appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.appunwrapper.com/2016/02/26/blackbox-walkthrough-guide-and-solutions/2/) it's a puzzle:

> 54: This is a new one. Use two hands/fingers to drag the screen to the
>   edge of the map and keep pulling so you see more and more dark space,
>   or the “grid.” Just keep pulling, even when the game tells you to
>   stop. Eventually you’ll get a new purple box.

The actual progression of the puzzle is reported to look something like this:

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]
[image: pic 3]
[image: pic 4]
[image: pic 5]